# What is OS apix module?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, solaris-zones

I'm using Solaris 10 Update 10 OS on my HPE BL460c Gen8 server. It is recommended by HPE to disable OS apix module,

> For ProLiant Gen8 servers, HPE Recommends disabling the OS apix
>   module. To disable the apix module add the following to the
>   /etc/system file and reboot the system: set apix_enable = 0

What is this **OS apix module**? What does actually happen when it is disabled?

Comment: *What does actually happen when it is disabled?*  Only way to know is try it and find out.  Before you do, though, make sure you have console access and know how to modify the boot parameters though the GRUB menu.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E29492/getov.html#fwbme  If you need to recover, add the `-a` option to the kernel GRUB boot parameters, boot, and you should be asked what file you want to use in place of the standard `/etc/system`.  You can either backup your original and use that or just use `/dev/null` for a default boot.

Answer (score 4):

It's an interface module for interrupts.  I can't say if the "issue" is on the hardware, OS side, or more likely combination.  My best guess is, that by disabling it, the OS will interface differently with the hardware.  You may want to contact HPe directly if you want specifics--there may even be a fw update or bios tweak negating the disabling.  That, plus the vendor should know best.  In theory.

Did you check the [Oracle Solaris Hardware Compatibility List (HCL)](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/hcl/index.html), to see if it gave any other guidance for your hardware?

You might find more specifics to your answer here as to what the apix module is -- if the man page didn't help:
  http://blahg.josefsipek.net/?tag=apix

As well as info on APIC:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller

Comment: I guess this **APIC** is different from _apix_ as apix is only found in Solaris. In most places, it is mentioned as a workaround to the bugs found in Solaris 10.